# Passing function to spawned MPI-process (mpi4py)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py, parfor

Is there a way to pass an arbitrary function with arguments to a newly spawned MPI child process with mpi4py? All I can find is

> MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable, args=[SomeScript.py], maxprocs=1, root=0)

but here, SomeScript.py is executed. Is it possible to pass some function instead, without having to turn that function into a script? And in case I have to turn it into a script, what's the best way to do that?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm trying to write a decorator that takes some function `SomeLoopStep(i)` and some data array and automatically runs the loop steps on each datapoint independently in parallel (inspired by MATLABs `parfor`). I'm new to parallelization, so if you think this is a terrible idea, please tell me why.

Comment: it would be much simpler to pass the function name as a parameter of `SomeScript.py` and update `SomeScript.py` to act accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you elaborate? I want this to work on arbitrary functions, so I can't write the functions into SomeScript.py beforehands.

Comment: Look into [`mpi4py.futures.MPIPoolExecutor`](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mpi4py.futures.html#mpipoolexecutor) and the way it works.